# INA219 to measure battery voltage

Tags: arduino, voltage, batteries, ina219, connecting

I want to measure the voltage of batteries. I am using an INA219 powered by an Arduino MKRWAN 1300. I have connected the INA219 to the MKRWAN as seen in the image below:

[image: Photo of Arduino and INA219 on breadboard]

However, I seem to have a hard time connecting the batteries to the INA219. How should I connect the batteries that the INA219 sensor can read its voltage?

Comment: The INA219 is intended to measure the voltage over a shunt resistor (see the datasheet). It would be possible to use batteries instead. Draw a schematic of what you've tried, and tell us what problem you got with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INA219 is a power monitor which is able to measure both bus voltage and load current. Although typical application setup is given in the datasheet, I'll try to draw a clearer version:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3X1kI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

`Rshunt` is a small resistance (e.g. 50 mR) to measure the current that the load draws from the supply.

**If you don't want to measure the current** (i.e. you want to measure the bus voltage only) then short `Vin+` and `Vin–` pins together to positive bus rail:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhkexS.png)</sup>

and set the operation mode to one of the "bus-voltage-only" modes:

[image]

---

If there's any available A/D channels on your Arduino then you can use it via a simple voltage divider, but you should take the maximum possible bus voltage into account i.e. the divider's output shouldn't exceed the A/D channel's max acceptable input voltage.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @RodaJhayanceJoceliLacson you can accept my answer by clicking the tick symbol under the points counter, so that the question doesn't remain open.